# cocos2d-x multi resolution appdelegate.cpp for ios, android, windows and blackberry devices

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x, appdelegate

I am making a cross platform game. I want to keep one appdelegate file with all the resolutions for all the devices so that I can make mega universal app with 2-3 sets of assets folder.

Could you guys share your appdelete.cpp file showing how you achieve for ios, android, blackberry and windows phone resolutions.

I mean is that even possible? I just would like to know how are people actually achieveing it? Do they create separate projects for each platform and change the code for the different platforms also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I’ve done.

```
    CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
    pDirector->setOpenGLView(pEGLView);
    // Set the design resolution
    pEGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(480, 640, kResolutionFixedWidth);
    CCSize windowSize = pDirector->getWinSize();
    CCLog("window width = %f, window height = %f", windowSize.width, windowSize.height);
```

You may vary the sizes 480 and 640 if you have different designs set, for e.g. (iphone, iPad etc). And write your code using width and height from windowSize.

Happy Coding.

Comment: what is the resolution of the assets for this setting? 640 by 480? so for say iphone, ipod I have 960x 640 and for iphone 5 1136 x 640(asset and design resolution)? And 1920x 1080 and 1280x 720 for hd and full hd(asset and design). then for 800 x 480 (screen)the rest use 320x 480(asset and design)???

Comment: This is design resolution in which you design assets. You may have different resolution assets for ipad, iphone etc, and use proper resources according to the device resolution. If you want to use same assets for all device, you have to stretch/scale the assets to exactly fit the device.

Comment: oh ok thanks really appreciate your help. suppose i have 9 sets of assets. for originalipod(480x320),ipod4, iphone5, ipad2, ipad3, 720p, 1080p,1280x 768 and 800x 480 how would i go about writing the code in the appdelegate to select the folder if the screen resolution matches the res of the asset, otherwise use assets of the original ipod and scale it to the device. Could you give a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow `kResolutionNoBorder` policy and position everything within VisibleRect. Check out HelloCpp sample.